# What is this anime song?

Tags: music, jigoku-shoujo

(Cross post from [/r/AnimeOST](http://www.reddit.com/r/AnimeOST/comments/2edqza/help_me_find_this_song/), where I didn't get any answer)

I have a song in mind recently, I'm pretty sure it comes from a well known anime that is less than 10 years old, but I can't remember which one.

Do you know what it is? I made a quick [music sheet here](http://www.noteflight.com/scores/view/4bd964b67346e78c59593cf6376a2f6bd882abad) so that you can see a bit what it sounds like in my head, I unfortunately can't remember any more.

[image]

There are supposed to be Japanese lyrics on the music.

Comment: Hint: press P or the red ▶ button on bottom-left of the page to play the tune.

Comment: Is it an opening or an ending song, do you know?

Comment: @ToshinouKyouko I unfortunately don't remember. I don't even remember what kind of anime it was from (but i'm pretty sure it's a well known one, I don't watch unusual animes). I tried finding it by listening to 6h of 'sad anime music' on YT but couldn't find it

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This melody seems to be "[Aizome](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_oIdIYHpHSo)" by Mamiko Noto, the ending theme of *[Jigoku Shoujo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hell_Girl)*. The melody seems to be playing the chorus of the song.

Comment: Piano ver for comparison: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bcPBFXVJiSY

Answer (score 0):

The first one that this tune brings to mind is the Attack on Titan opening song - "Guren no Yumiya" by Linked Horizon, which of course is very recent . It doesn't match the tune exactly, but it's a chance it could be because of memory.

[Here's an acoustic cover version of the song](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pCHzLFC-CmU)

The tune seems really familiar to me, so I'm hesitant about this answer, perhaps some more details like style/genre of music would help.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's something more calm, with a women's voice over the music. It's supposed to be slower than the sheet I uploaded (idk how to change the tempo on that website)

Comment: The themes are either quite very similar or the same though..

Comment: I somehow put a bounty on the wrong question (this one was supposed to go on a question where Ezui had answered), but hey, I owe you a 50-rep bounty and you happen to have answered this question, so here you go.

Answer (score 0):

The melody really reminds me of main theme from Mahou Shoujo Tai Arusu. Especially this part : http://youtu.be/foKqCYEYnpo?t=45s

It has slow tempo, but it doesn't have any lyrics. But I might be mistaking it because you used similar instruments in your music sheet.

Comment: It isn't this one, but thanks for the try ! You made me discover a new awesome soundtrack :)